# Finding regular differential $n$-forms on projective varieties.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Do you know if there are known methods, a given projective variety, for finding explicitly the generators of $H^0(X,K_X)$ (when it $\kappa(X)\neq \infty$).
I've tried to find them explicitly for surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$, but also for the first non-trivial case of q smoot quartic surfaces looks to be difficult.
For example how to find the form for the Fermat Quartic
$$X_0^4+...X_3^4=0$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_residue